# Invite for Careers 2.0

Tags: discussion, jobs

How do I get an invite for [Careers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Careers) 2.0? Do I have to have a certain amount of reputation points? (I only have about 1.5K).

I don't know anyone on Stack Overflow personally, so I don't expect anyone to proactively just invite me because they love my work, because they've never seen it.

Comment: @ckitt, M.R. you are welcome.

Comment: I received my invite from the site. It cited my activity in the android tag as the reason. I first thought this odd as python is my number 1 tag, then I realized that in sheer number of answers, Android is my number 1 tag. I would guess that an automatic invite requires you to have at least one tag with X posts with a combined score of at least Y.

Comment: I believe you are right my friend. just be better at android -- its probably in so demand right now, got my invite and my reputation was just less than 60 that time.

Answer (score 7):

I got mine some time after I got my silver Python badge (400 upvotes in the Python tag).

> We’re impressed by your “python” tag answers on Stack Overflow. In recognition of your generous spirit, we’d like to invite you to create a professional profile on [Stack Overflow Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/invitation?code=e883c3a5-307a-44da-b224-0265002223c5).

I'm not sure if they give out invites based on other criteria, but demonstrating a lot of knowledge in a particular tag is a good way to get in. Getting invited by someone who has already been invited is a better way to get in.

Answer (score 2):

[Joel sometimes tweets invites](https://twitter.com/spolsky/status/99541956425818112).

Answer (score 2):

People who initially paid for the service were automatically given access to version 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually request for a profile [here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one). I submitted my details just in case they'd take me and they did accept my application even though I had no silver badges at the time. I think activity in a single site or several sites is enough to get an invite.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes people gives an invitation for free. Because they are altruist maybe. (I got one that way.)

You generally get an invitation from Stack Exchange based on your work on the site; I heard expertise in a given tag is required.

Answer (score 0):

I received mine when I actively shot up on the `Android` tags list (i'm top 10% now -- but I think it was top 30% then). I had been using SO religiously, and I got a similar message to the one discussed by Rafe:

> We’re impressed by your “android” tag answers on Stack Overflow. In
>   recognition of your generous spirit, we’d like to invite you to create
>   a professional profile on Stack Overflow Careers 2.0.